# How do I change the design of the UIKeyboardType.NumberPad to a custom custom design in Xamarin.iOS/Monotouch?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, keyboard, xamarin

I have a xamarin.ios app with custom design and would like to adapt the keypad to the design I have. So I am trying to hook up a custom design for the UIKeyboardType.NumberPad similar to the image below. How do I go about this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please decrease screenshot size. It's color with so much size hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no approved API to customize keyboards - even their appearance.

A *possible* solution (that I suggest you to **avoid**) is to [manipulate the subviews](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html) to modify their properties. Note that that could easily break between iOS releases (as the internals can changes any time).

Now if your goal is to only use something like `UIKeyboardType.NumberPad` then you might find it easier to build your *own keyboard* from buttons (this one is simple, it's only 12 buttons and it's not affected by the current locale/region). That will give you a lot more control on it's appearance and won't break in future version of iOS.